# React router redirect to root blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I can see `Login` component in `/`.
I can see `Home` component in `/home` (when logged in).

But when I access `/home` without logging in, I get redirected to `/`, but it's showing a blank page.

Why is it not showing me the `Login` component?

Here's the `ProtectedRoute` component I use:

```js
const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, isAuth, ...rest}) => {
  if (Cookies.get('token')) {
    isAuth = true
  }
  return <Route {...rest} render={props => (isAuth ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect exact to="/" />)} />
}
```

Here's my route in `App.js`:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.App}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={Home} isAuth={this.props.auth} />
        <Route render={() => <h1>Not found</h1>} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here's `BrowserRouter` as `Router` in `index.js`:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,

  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your component in a [`BrowserRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)? [It works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/0py890xqlv).

Comment: I wrapped the entire `App` in `BrowserRouter` is that what you mean? (added to my question)

Comment: Yes, that looks about right. Very strange. I don't know what it might be then. You could try to put the `Router` inside the `Provider`, but that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Yup, have moved it in, but its still the same issue. Will keep it there anyway since it seems better that way.

Answer (score 3):

Realised the `Switch` case isn't updating even though the route did change when redirected using `react developer tools`.

Finally got it working after I moved `BrowserRouter`(as `Router`) to wrap only the `Switch` cases.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.App}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route render={() => <h1>Not found</h1>} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This fixed it for me as well! Thanks! Would love to know why. I originally had BrowserRouter in index.tsx and the Switch in App.tsx